# Exception when trying to convert a String to a java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, exception

I have a JLabel with a date written as a String and I want to convert it into a sql.Date, but when I try to convert it, it run an exception. The date value is passed from a server with RMI.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

This is the RMI code:

```
PrenotazioniVaccini infoPrenotazione = null;    
    try {
        infoPrenotazione = stub.getPrenotazioneVaccinazione(tf_Cf.getText());
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    label_DataVaccino.setText(infoPrenotazione.getData());
```

This is the label code:

```
label_DataVaccino = new JLabel("");
label_DataVaccino.setBounds(0, 320, 400, 25);
label_DataVaccino.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
label_DataVaccino.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
panel_AddVaccinatoGUI.add(label_DataVaccino);
```

This is where the Exception run:

```
private void registraVaccinato() {
   String data = label_DataVaccino.getText();
   Date dataVaccino = Date.valueOf(data);
   System.out.println(dataVaccino);
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql/java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:141)
    at centrivaccinali.AddVaccinatoGUI.registraVaccinato(AddVaccinatoGUI.java:294)
    at centrivaccinali.AddVaccinatoGUI$3.actionPerformed(AddVaccinatoGUI.java:282)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    ...
```

I've used this guide to convert a String into a sql.Date: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-sql-date

Comment: Why, specifically, are you wanting to use `java.sql.Date` instead of modern types, particularly `java.time.LocalDate`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Because I obtain the String type from a calendar created with jDatePicker.jar and I need to register the choosen date into a DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IllegalArgumentException is when the argument is illegal or not proper.

The syntax for the data string needs to be in this format: yyyy-mm-dd. There are further restrictions like mm < 1 and mm > 12.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I've wrote the date in the format yyyy/mm/dd but it didn't works then watching your answer I've noticed that the date you wrote is in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @Nico FYI, the `YYYY-MM-DD` format complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Stick to those standard formats when serializing textual date-time values, that is purpose of the standard. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.